# Is there a way to play Twilight Imperium's "age of empire" variant with Shattered Empire's strategy cards?

Tags: house-rules, expansions, twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

The third edition of *Twilight Imperium* has become one of the most-played games as of late, and we have finally begun to incorporate the first expansion into the game. In the core *TI3* rules is an excellent variant, called *age of empire*, that makes the entire public objective deck accessible by the fourth round. We have a lot more fun playing with this variant, but ran into difficulty when incorporating *Shattered Empire's* new strategy cards.

*Shattered Empire's* eighth strategy card, *bureaucracy*, primarily deals with revealing objective cards, which is pointless with *age of empire's* fully-revealed setup. We ran into this problem the first and only time we played, and could not figure out a solution—letting the *bureaucracy* card pile up with bonus counters until there were none left. It was a disappointing way to end my new favourite game. I otherwise found these new cards to be much more interesting, so it would be nice to use them.

Has anyone figured out a clever way to modify their rules so as to incorporate both ? I would very much like to keep in the spirit of the card(s), but every modification I have come up with is terribly boring.

Answer (score 5):

As it says in the rules for Shattered Empire, if you're using the Age of Empire variant, you have to use the Imperial II strategy card rather than Bureaucracy.

Comment: ^this guy gets it

Answer (score 1):

We usually play with *Age of empire* option and *variant strategy card*, using this set of strategy cards:

- initiative
- diplomacy II
- political
- logistic
- trade II
- warfare
- technology II
- imperial II

It leads to very smooth matches, so it became our standard set up.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is very old, but I've enjoyed using the "Red Tape Bureaucracy" Variant, that is popular with some community members.

The "Red Tape Bureaucracy" Strategy Card can be seen (and printed from) here: http://checkwolf.com/ti3/images/high%20resolution/jpeg/sc%20bureaucracy_front.jpg

The rules discussion and explanation is here: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/757071/red-tape-bureaucracy

In short:

-Setup the Age of Empire Objective Deck as normal

-When dealing out the Objective Deck, place one "Red Tape" marker (of your choice) on each dealt Public Objective Card

-Objective Cards that have a Red Tape marker cannot be claimed

-Red Tape markers are removed via the "Red Tape Bureaucracy" Strategy Card

I hope this helps!